# Question on Step X of Rudin's proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

I am working through Rudin's proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem in his Real and Complex Analysis texbook.  The statement of the theorem is as follows:
[image]

I am stuck on Step X.  The proof of Step X is given by Rudin as:
[image]

My Question is about the sets $E_i$.  Specifically, I don't understand Rudin's explanation of why these sets have to be Borel sets.  I understand why they are disjoint, why their union is K, and why f is a Borel measurable function, but I don't see why this implies the sets $E_i$ are Borel sets.  I understand that K is a Borel set because it's closed, and so if the set {$x: y_{i-1} <f(x)\le y_i$} were a Borel set, then $E_i$ would be a Borel set since it's the intersection of two Borel sets.  My confusion is about how we know the set {$x: y_{i-1} <f(x)\le y_i$} is a Borel set. Any elucidation on this point would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $f$ is continuous the intersection on the left hand side is an intersection of a an open and a closed set, thus the intersection is a Borel set
$$\{ x: y_{i-1} <f(x) \} \cap \{ x: f(x)\le y_i \} =\{ x: y_{i-1} <f(x)\le y_i \}  $$